# How write a Unit-Test For method call after Angular Broadcasting event

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am attempting to test that my controller opens a modal when a broadcast event is fired.
The code works fine but the expectation always fails:

```
it('should open model on idleStart', function () {
    $scope.$on('idleStart', function(){
       expect(dsModalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('idleStart');

 });
```

I assume it fails because of its asynchronous nature of a broadcast.  The controller hasn't had time to open the modal.
So I added in the done() method and put it in a setTimeout function

```
it('should open model on idleStart', function (done) {
    $scope.$on('idleStart', function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        expect(dsModalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
      }, 500);
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('idleStart');

 });
```

It said it was passing now,  but I had a suspicion so I put in a debugger statement. The code in the setTimeout is not run until after the test says it has passed successfully.

```
it('should open modal on idleStart', function (done) {
  $scope.$on('idleStart', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      debugger //This code is run after the test says it is completed and passed successfully.
      done();
    }, 500);
  });
  $scope.$broadcast('idleStart');

});
```

I thought by adding the done argument into the it function that it wouldn't say it was done until the done function was called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install karma-jasmine was giving me the 1.x version.

I needed to be using Jasmine 2.0

```
npm install karma-jasmine@2_0 --save-dev
```